# Add a method on Function.prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am reading 'javascript:The Good Parts' these days,I get some code confuses me :

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
     this.prototype[name] = func;
     return this;
};

console.log(Function.method)  
//It returns `function(name, func) {this.prototype[name] = func;return this;}`    which defined above.
```

In my opinion, when using 'Function.prototype.method', the `method` method will  used by all Function objects,why can it be used by Function itself?

And when I change the two `Function` words above to `Array` ,it returns `undefined`.

```
Array.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
     this.prototype[name] = func;
     return this;
} ;

console.log(Array.method)   //It returns `undefined`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my opinion, when using 'Function.prototype.method', the method `method` will used by all Function objects

Correct. (It will be inherited by all function objects, not necessarily *used* by them.)

> why can it be used by Function itself?

Because `Function` is a function object, so like all functions it inherits from `Function.prototype`.

> And when I change the two Function words above to Array ,it returns undefined.

Because you've added the method to arrays (which inherit from `Array.prototype`), not functions, but `Array` is a function, not an array.

Comment: Thank you ,You are always the first man answers my question.I understand the first and third item  you list above.                                Yes,`Function` is a function Object, Here It acts as both `object` and `constructor` which baffles me .

Comment: @johnny_trs: Functions are objects, and any function can be called as a constructor (except arrow and generator functions in ES2015 and above). Of course, most functions aren't meant to be called as constructors.